# Which version of python does IronPython 2.6.2 support?

Tags: python, ironpython

Which version of python does  IronPython 2.6.2 support?

Comment: If I don't know anything about versions, it does not mean that I should get a -1. The purpose of stackoverflow is to help you learn new things. Please explain the -1 whoever gave it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [release page](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/releases/view/12482) for IronPython 2.6 state that it supports Python 2.6.

Comment: Does 2.6.6 differ from 2.6.0 in such important ways that alternative language implementations should care about that? Or should you care?

Comment: @Programmer: what part of the release page confuses you?  2.6 seems to mean 2.6.  That includes 2.6.6, doesn't it?  Or is there some reason for doubting that 2.6 includes 2.6.6?  If so, what's the reason?  Also, why aren't you asking the Iron Python team for details?  Are they unresponsive?

Comment: 2.6.6 has some bug fixes for bugs in 2.6.0

Comment: @Programmer: IronPython does not attempt to replicate CPython bugs. It undoubtedly has bugs of its own which it is attempting to solve. Python 2.6 is a level of compatibility: both CPython and IronPython will attempt to support that as well as possible while the version number starts with 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it obvious that it's 2.6?

Comment: 2.6.2 is the version of Iron Python, NOT THE VERSION OF PYTHON THAT IRON PYTHON SUPPORTS. PLEASE GIVE ME LINK WHERE IT IS MENTIONED

Comment: I am not very sure about above, just my 0.02